# Issue with Forwarded Header and Multiple Values in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

According to the [RFC7239 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239), syntax for **Forwarded Header** is as follows:

```
Forwarded: by=<identifier>;for=<identifier>;host=<host>;proto=<http|https>
```

These values are used by Spring (all recent versions), if present, in order to reflect the client-originated protocol and address (when allowed through a configuration). There is a problem when using multiple values in this header:

```
# Multiple values can be appended using a comma
Forwarded: for=192.0.2.43,for=198.51.100.17;proto=https;host=xxx.yyy.com;by=10.97.9.10
```

The code in [`UriComponentsBuilder#adaptFromForwardedHeaders:798-800`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/a4dc13a0435484d5704e72a94a4e41c690afb381/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.java#L800) gets the first **Forwarded Header**, if multiple are found, splits it by comma and uses only the first part:

```
    UriComponentsBuilder adaptFromForwardedHeaders(HttpHeaders headers) {
        try {
            String forwardedHeader = headers.getFirst("Forwarded");
            if (StringUtils.hasText(forwardedHeader)) {
                String forwardedToUse = StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(forwardedHeader, ",")[0];
                ....
    }
```

Using the example above, the `forwardedToUse` variable becomes `Forwarded: for=192.0.2.43` where all useful information is trimmed.

Is this really an issue or there is something that I am missing? And if this is really a problem, how can I deal with it.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is an issue in Spring with Forwarded header in case of multiple values. It is fixed with the commit below and will be available in next release:

- **GitHub Issue**: [Issue with Forwarded Header and Multiple Values](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25737)
- **Spring Framework Commit**: [Do not tokenize Forward header value](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/07d2c08f48beb916427e02f0601c19ec53a40c38)
- **Release**: [Spring 5.2.9.RELEASE](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/pull/262)